# Take snapshot of section of webpage and save it to a server as same image (i.e. update it)

Tags: snapshot, updating

I want to show, on a site that accepts only bbcode, a snapshot of a section of an external site. This section is constantly changing so I want to know if there's a way to automatically take a snapshot and save it to any server as same image so it's always updating on the bbcode-only site. Any help?

Really sorry if it's a duplicate, I tried my best searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phantomJS for doing it.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("http://www.google.com", function start(status) {
  page.render('google_home.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
  phantom.exit();
});
```

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html)

Comment: Oh dang, PhantomJS, I see... Thanks !